# How do I fix an fopen error and fopen_s error?

Tags: c

I am having trouble fixing an fopen error in my code.  It recommends that I change it to fopen_s whereupon I receive an error stating that there are too few arguments in function call.  This was my original code.

```
FILE* tpnWg = fopen("telephone.txt", "a+");
```

After doing a little research I have have tried changing it to the code below.

```
FILE*tpnWg;
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&tpnWg, "telephone.txt.", "a+");
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please *show the complete, actual error message* - don't just call it "an fopen error"; that could mean any number of different things. We can't read either your mind or your terminal window.

Comment: My current error states that tpnWg is undefined.

Comment: `fopen_s` is weird Microsoft non-standard stuff and I'd highly advise you just ignore Visual Studio's bad advice to switch to it.

Comment: "My current error states"... No, we don't want a summary; we want the *complete, actual* error message. Go into the window where the error message is displayed, copy that text, edit your post, paste in the error text, and format it as if it were code.

Comment: Error C2065 'tpnWg': undeclared identifier

Comment: Put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1` at the top of your file (above all of the `#include`s) and make sure you are including stdio.h. Revert to `fopen` and go on with your project.

Comment: Re tpnWg, are you sure that was the *first* error message?